# Как прочитать hex код из одного байта?

Tags: java, android

```
recordingStream = Connection.getInputStream();
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {  // 1 раз 1 байт.
    if (recordingStream.read(buffer, 0, ikk) != -1 && isRecording) {
        //writer.write(buffer, 0, ikk);
        String lin = new String(buffer, 0, ikk);
        //из потока в String(?) прочитался один байт - ikk=1
    }
}
```

Дальше нужно прочитать `lin` и вывести его hex (hex там такой: `04`. Вот `04` и нужно прочитать уже в следующий `String` как текст).

Проще говоря, декодировать один байт из hex-а в текст.

Answer (score -4):

```
String inputString = lin;
byte[] byteArray = inputString.getBytes();
String xx = Arrays.toString(byteArray);
char my = xx.charAt(1);
```

Итого: my=4
То что надо. Удачный день. Но по моему не эргономично.

Comment: @Regent это ответ на вопрос, просто он странно оформлен.

Comment: @PashaPash первая редакция "ответа", к которой относился мой комментарий, не походила на ответ от слова "полностью". К текущей редакции (да и ко второй) вопросов нет.